# Probability problems associated with collecting all types of cards

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations, coupon-collector

When a person buys 15 boxes, there are 5 cards in the box, and the types of the 5 cards are different from each other (however, the relationship between the cards in the box and other cards in other boxes is uncertain, that iss random). This person wants to collect all types of cards (that is, 45 types) by buying these 15 boxes. Now, please work out the probability of his success.

Comment: Look up the coupon collector problem.

Comment: "(however, the relationship between the cards in the box and other cards in other boxes is uncertain)." The answer is also uncertain unless you tell us how the cards wer filled in the first place !

Comment: @ true blue anil    That process is random, but I think there is a certain answer we can find, just like "the coupon collector problem"

Comment: @ Ross Millikan   Thank you for reminding me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work out the problem using inclusion-exclusion, focusing on the *missing* cards

The needed probability will be

$1 - P$(at least one card missing - at least 2 cards missing + .....)

and the *Pr* of at least *k* cards missing is

$= \dbinom{45}{k}\left[\dbinom{45-k}{5}\right]^{15}\bigg{/}\left[\dbinom{45}{5}\right]^{15}$

Comment: Sorry, in https://www.desmos.com/ I used the method you provided to calculate the result, the result is greater than one - I don't see the flaw of your method, but I hope you can calculate it by yourself and verify your method, let me know whether the deviation of the result is a method error or an algorithm error. Thank you for your efforts!

Comment: The formula is ok. Did you handle the signs in inclusion-exclusion properly ? I'm not facing that problem.  Here is the full formula, (45pick5)^-15*sum_{j=0}^45((-1)^j (45pick j)*((45-j)pick5)^15)

Comment: Which gives an answer of $\approx 0.0000154065$, unless I have miscalculated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I know this simple question is a waste of your time, but it is difficult for me, a Chinese high school student, to understand it. Anyway, now I know the way. Thank you very much!